# Make Entire Result set into a Single Row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

i have to convert the entire result in Oracle into a single row result set with different column names

I have tried with some self joins but not appears to be working .

Expected output

[image: ][1]]

[image: Expected here]

Comment: Check out the `PIVOT` keyword. That ought to get you where you want to go. Though, you might run into problems with no definite end of the names in the table.

Comment: What if you have more than 3 rows to pivot? And how would you use the result? This is probably something you should do in a presentation layer, not a query.

Comment: I Will have maximum 5 rows with each row have around 7 fields .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each row a unique number and then `PIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ssn, first_name, last_name ) AS
  SELECT 123456789, 'VKP', 'KKO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 987654321, 'ABC', 'XYZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 332211456, 'PQR', 'GHJ' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT "1_SSN"        AS SSN_1,
       "1_FIRST_NAME" AS FIRST_NAME_1,
       "1_LAST_NAME"  AS LAST_NAME_1,
       "2_SSN"        AS SSN_2,
       "2_FIRST_NAME" AS FIRST_NAME_2,
       "2_LAST_NAME"  AS LAST_NAME_2,
       "3_SSN"        AS SSN_3,
       "3_FIRST_NAME" AS FIRST_NAME_3,
       "3_LAST_NAME"  AS LAST_NAME_3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT(
  MAX( SSN        ) AS SSN,
  MAX( FIRST_NAME ) AS first_name,
  MAX( LAST_NAME  ) AS last_name
  FOR rn IN (1, 2, 3)
)
```

**Output**:

> ```
>     SSN_1 | FIRST_NAME_1 | LAST_NAME_1 |     SSN_2 | FIRST_NAME_2 | LAST_NAME_2 |     SSN_3 | FIRST_NAME_3 | LAST_NAME_3
> --------: | :----------- | :---------- | --------: | :----------- | :---------- | --------: | :----------- | :----------
> 123456789 | VKP          | KKO         | 987654321 | ABC          | XYZ         | 332211456 | PQR          | GHJ
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1001bcbfe39edacf1aa940101a459a87)*

Comment: Great , Working exactly as expected . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just get this job done anyway,easiest option would be :-

```
   select t1.ssn as ssn,t1.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NAME, t1.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME from test_tab t1
  union
  select t1.ssn_1 as ssn,t1.FIRST_NAME_1 as FIRST_NAME, t1.LAST_NAME_1  as LAST_NAME from test_tab t1
  union
  select t1.ssn_2 as ssn,t1.FIRST_NAME_2 as FIRST_NAME, t1.LAST_NAME_2  as LAST_NAME from test_tab t1;
```

For sure other option can be checked for more dynamic data.

Comment: This does not convert the multiple input rows to a single output row.